# using ajax for change website language

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I Have very simple PHP html code for change my website language and I need to use Ajax to not-reload after select language but honestly I never used ajax before and I don't have any idea how to use that.

I google it and found some code but I fail.

HTML:

```
 <form action="" method="get">
      <input type="submit" value="per" id="per" name="per">
      <input type="submit" value="eng" id="eng" name="eng">
</form>
```

PHP :

```
function lang()
{
    $lang = 'per';
    if (isset($_GET['per']))
        return $lang = 'per';
    else
        return $lang = 'eng';
}
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'index.blade.php',
    data: {name: 'per'},
    success: function(data){
               alert(data);
               window.location.reload();
             }
    });
```

All Code's are at one page named

```
index.blade.php
```

php code working fine just need for ajax to not-reload page when I click buttons

Comment: Are you trying prevent page reloading after ajax success response

Comment: yes. that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: but window.location.reload() gonna refresh the page if you implement that

Comment: did you try to remove window.location.reload() part

Comment: I remove window.location.reload() and still page reload . i think Ajax code even not work

Comment: you can try to use different php file like lang.php and call it in ajax

Comment: at the same time you should remove window.location.reload() part

Comment: is this a laravel app?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="" >
    <button type="submit" id="button1">Click
    </button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="2.js"></script>-->
</html>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    //alert("hello");
    e.preventDefault();  //a button's default behavior is to submit the form which this function prevents
        $.ajax({
        url:"example.php",
        success:function(result){

            alert(result);
            location.href=location.href; //here you can specify where you want to get your ajax call to redirect to.
        }

    })
    return false;

})
```

php file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
?>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest studying a few tutorials on Ajax, I will try to briefly touch the subject here.

First of all, when doing Ajax, you basically call a web page or script (an actual url, not a function written in PHP). The result that you get (HTML, XML, CSS, JSON, JPG), you can use in your code, insert ii in the DOM, change the document, etc.

In my opinion, changing the language is a site-wide action that should probably be implemented as a normal call. Genearaly, if you change the language, then the whole page should be translated, from the top (title) to the last bit of text down before the closing body.

If you just need to change a small portion of the web page, please see the URL
[jQuery get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

The page uses an example

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

that performs what you want, just change the url. Hope I helped a bit.

Comment: yes i know i should study tutorials  but unfortunately for now I don't have time but I gonna study Angular later. second : are you say that in this case reload page is not important?

Comment: Reloading the page should not change the language. The language should be defined somehow, like http://srv.tld/page?lang=en, or http://srv.tld/en/page, or http://en.srv.tld/page, the PHP should parse the requested language and make the response

Comment: Other than the above, people tend to put the language in the session, but this is very a very bad strategy for SEO, because the url http://srv.tld/page, would be used for all languages (depending on the user selection)

Comment: In addition to the above, for SEO, you should use links for the different languages, instead of forms.