# Changing lang attribute of HTML page without reload

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML structure we have

```
<html lang="tr">
```

It is very useful when you need to transform text to upper/lowercase with different languages.

```
<div style="text-transform: uppercase;" id="asd">iğüşçıâ</div>
```

I'm working on a single page application, so I can't refresh the page.

But web application is multilingual so I need to change "lang" attribute of html tag without refreshing page.

I tried:

```
document.documentElement.lang = "en"
```

It doesn't affect **text-transform: uppercase;**.
If I manually change the html lang attribute in HTML file and reload the page, it works fine.

How can I done this? Is there a way?

Thanks advance.

**update:**
Some Stackoverflow users marked this is about ajax, php things. I'm sure sure this question never asked before. This question **NOT** about ajax and php.

Comment: Why do you expect it to affect `text-transform`? You used a style attribute so it *always* apples. There's no condition based on language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using ajax for change website language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342464/using-ajax-for-change-website-language)

Comment: The `lang` in `<html>` doesn't translate your page it is only good for search engines it just tells them what language your page is

Comment: @midrizi Thanks for your answers but I didn't mean translates. I wrote "transform" to uppercase or to lowercase.  "text-transform: uppercase;" feature taking culture from html lang attribute.

Comment: @Quentin "text-transform: uppercase;" feature taking culture from html lang attribute. Double check please. Or you can lab it.

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu thats an interesting question. i was digging: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-lang-why
but couldn't find the answer for your question. for screenreaders i would say its ok to change it dynamically but for css-uppercase behaviour obviously not....hmmm would be great to have some more info on this one since we have a lot of dynamic pages (spa) this days...

Comment: btw. if you add your lang="en" tag to your div directly (dynamically) it should work
even better after reading the spec: https://www.w3.org/html/wg/wiki/ChangedAttributeLang
section 8.1.2 it says that the lang attribute gets inherited. 
so that could mean that you maybe can set it on the body tag or so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angularjs to change the language without reloading the page.
For  changing the language, you can use the angularjs $scope and change the language of HTML without reloading.

Comment: Web application is vanilla js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setAttribute for changing or adding new attributes from elements;

```
document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang","tr")
```

```js
function changeLangTr() {
 document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang","tr")
 getText()
}
function changeLangEn() {
 document.documentElement.setAttribute("lang","en")
 getText()
}

function getText() {
 var node = document.getElementById('text')
}
```

```css
p {
 margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p.upper {
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
p#info {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: red;
 margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<html name="html" lang="tr">
 <body>
  <div id="home">
   <button onclick='changeLangTr()'>
    Change Language TR
   </button>
   <button onclick='changeLangEn()'>
    Change Language EN
   </button>
   <p id="text">
    Türkçe Karakterlerin Kullanımı (iğüşçıâ)
   </p>
   
   <strong>Now:</strong>
   <p id="info">
    Turkish Lowercase
   </p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Didn't work unless rerendering CSS codepen.io/Nagibaba/pen/ZEBPbQP